# spring security login 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

im exploring a little of spring.
i got across spring boot for easy endpoints see:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/sample")
    @ResponseBody
    String sample() {
        return "Hello sample!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sample2")
    @ResponseBody
    String sample2() {
        return "Hello sample secured!";
    }
}
```

logically the endpoints are accessible on localhost:8181/sample

but on using spring security the "protected" endpoint becames unaccessible because the login page gives me 404

[image: login page gives me 404]

my security class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sample" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

i am able to access **/sample** as is not protected. but unable to access **/sample2** as it redirects to **/login**

im configuring my security class according to this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am able to access `/sample` as is not protected. But unable to access
>   /sample2 as it redirects to `/login`

Because you have not by-passed `/sample2` in your security configuration.

```
 .antMatchers("/sample2" ).permitAll()
```

Another thing is that as you have specified custom login page

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
```

you have to provide a login page.

Comment: isnt /login the default login page? the one that appears as a simple form?

Comment: ^ I confirm that

Answer (score 0):

Inject `userDetailsService` into `authenticationProvider`:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
```

Add this configuration to spring security:

```
    .antMatchers("/sample2").hasRole("USER")
```